# Permission not maintained for newly created files while using vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, vagrant

I'm using vagrant with precise64 box & a Laravel 4 project.
I've set Storage folder to be writable (777 only works for me) and every time a new file created, session for example, I need to manually set yet again the new file to be writable.

Is there any option to set newly created files to be writable in order to prevent this kind of issue in the future?

edit: Here is an example of ll -la output on the session folder containing new session (done from the vagrant box), maybe it'll help.

```
vagrant@precise64:/myfinalproject$ ll -la ./app/storage/sessions/
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul  9 04:29 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jun 10 12:57 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   13 Jun 10 12:57 .gitignore*
-rw------- 1 vagrant vagrant  229 Jul  9 04:29 sess_u8ov414cgie6v3afmkgn3net33
```

Comment: Can you show us the result of the command (after SSHing into your vagrant box) `ll -la` on the directory with the files after they are newly created?

Comment: I've edited the question and added what you've asked.

Comment: What do you mean by `storage folder`?  Do you mean `synced folder`?

Comment: Storage folder is just a folder in Laravel 4 framework which needed to be writeble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your apache user and group to vagrant. In ubuntu, edit /etc/apache2/envvars and change

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

to

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=vagrant
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=vagrant
```

Comment: This seems to fix constant issues with Homestead when you install apache inside of it. With the Homestead.yaml file you cannot define the 'owner' and 'group'

Comment: Yes! All the other solutions suggested chmod to 77x. This is the only solution that worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was having a very similar, possibly the same, permissions issue. I could view the site once and then all requests after would result in a permission error.

Try adding the following code to your VagrantFile:

```
# Set the ownership of the app/storage directory
config.vm.synced_folder "app/storage", "/vagrant/app/storage", :owner => 'www-data', :group => 'www-data'
```

Hopefully that helps you. The following source provided me with the solution: https://github.com/experience/vagrant-laravel-application/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help me. no matter what I try as for the name/group name (tried my user as in my host) nothing works but `vagrant` as owner and group. which gives me same issue.
any other owner or group result: `The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!`

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `shared folder` or `synced folder`, you may use optional arguments to control the permission:

```
config.vm.share_folder "shared_folder", "/myfinalproject", "/host/path", :owner => "vagrant", :group => "vagrant"
```

**Reference**

http://rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant/Vagrant/Config/VMConfig%3ashare_folder

**Source**

```
# File 'lib/vagrant/config/vm.rb', line 53

def share_folder(name, guestpath, hostpath, opts=nil)
  @shared_folders[name] = {
    :guestpath => guestpath.to_s,
    :hostpath => hostpath.to_s,
    :create => false,
    :owner => nil,
    :group => nil,
    :nfs   => false,
    :transient => false,
    :extra => nil
  }.merge(opts || {})
end
```

Comment: Didn't helped, I keep on getting permission issues on new files created by the "system" such as session files.

Answer (score 0):

Change it so you are syncing the whole laravel app folder. Not just the specific storage directory.
I had the same issue as you, I was only syncing the storage dir. Laravel was able to create a new file in the session dir, but later could not write to the file it just made.

Here is my new config

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", :owner => 'www-data', :group => 'www-data'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be searching this question but is having this problem when using **VirtualBox** (and you are using shared folders):

```
// Get your user id,gid (in this case I'm root):
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

// Add apache to vbox group
usermod -a -G vboxsf apache

// Get apache's id,gid
# id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),499(vboxsf)

// Update fstab mount to use these id,gid
# vi /etc/fstab
      [ add this line to the file ]
      shared-name  /path/to/guest/shared/folder/here  vboxsf  rw,uid=0,gid=0,uid=48,gid=48  0  0
```